# How to get the tables extracted from split documents using apache poi?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

Link I used to refer for getting split documents by Tasha , Here Document Split is there but tables are not extracted.

[Apache POI - Split Word document (docx) to pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38047893/apache-poi-split-word-document-docx-to-pages)

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. In order to increase your chances of receiving a positive response to your query please read and consider the points raised in the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of this site.

Comment: I believe this could be the best possible way to ask the question for the situation .